# Negated regex does not work in RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write rules for mod_rewrite. I need to redirect all requests that begin with "/api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/" to app.php and send 400 Bad Request redirect for another requests.

[Mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) says:

> In mod_rewrite the ! character can be used before a regular expression
> to negate it. This is, a string will be considered to have matched
> only if it does not match the rest of the expression.

So, I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [L]
RewriteRule !^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ - [R=400]
```

If I use this, I get 400 Bad Request for every request.

I've tried also:

```
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [S=1]
RewriteRule !^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ - [R=400]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUIEST_URI} !^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/
RewriteRule !^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ - [R=400]
```

I always get 400 Bad Request for every request.

It looks like the last rule works always. I can't understand why.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [L]
RewriteRule !^a - [R=400]
```

It works correctly. I get 400 Bad Request for every request that doesn't begin with "a", redirect to app.php works too. But if I add something to the rule, it doesn't work anymore.

```
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [L]
RewriteRule !^api - [R=400]
```

This one doesn't work (400 Bad Request for every request again).

I can't understand what's the difference between ~^a and ~^api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude your `app.php` file otherwise your rule will also map it to `400` error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ app.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app\.php [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/ - [R=400]
```

The reason why you are seeing a `400` bed request on all URIs is because your first rule matchs any requests matching the pattern `^api/v[0-9.]+/app/[a-z]+/` and rewrites the URI to `app.php` . Your web server reads the htaccess file again in order to serve `app.php` and your second rule matches, `app.php` gets rewritten to `R=400` .

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation, it works and now I understand how it works.

Comment: @Saband Your welcome! Glad I could be of help,cheers .